# Convolving impulse response of a 1st order low pass filter produces extremely distorted audio

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, signal-processing

I am working on designing a filter bank for an analog audio project and I want to test different filter topologies (bessel, chebyshev, butterworth etc.) before moving on to circuit simulation. I'm starting with a simple example to test the process - a first order low pass filter. I load my wav file (3 seconds long), take the ifft of the laplace transform of the filter, then I convolve it with the audio.

I haven't attached the audio, but I can assure you no low-pass filtering is happening. The audio is extremely distorted.

```html
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
import sounddevice as sd


samplerate, data = wavfile.read('sample.wav')
w0 = 2*np.pi*170 #cutoff freq (1/RC)
f = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data), d = 1/samplerate)

transfer = w0 / (1j*2*np.pi*f + w0)
impulse_response = np.fft.ifft(transfer)

filtered_signal = np.convolve(data, impulse_response, mode='same')
filtered_signal = filtered_signal.real

sd.play(filtered_signal.real, samplerate)
sd.wait()
```

P.S. I recently discovered that LTSpice accepts wav files as signal inputs, and I got the expected result when I implemented this with a voltage source, resistor, and capacitor. Can't quite figure out the DSP here.

Answer (score 0):

When you read wave files with [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) it will determine the sample type from file header, you are most likely returning a `int16` array.

When you convolve you are generating a complex value, `filtered_signal.real` will be either `float32` or `float64`.

```
filtered_signal = np.convolve(np.float64(data), impulse_response, mode='same')
# Make sure the filter didn't cause saturation
assert np.all(abs(filtered_signal.real) < 2**15-1)
filtered_signal = np.int16(filtered_signal.real)
sd.play(filtered_signal.real, samplerate)
```

The sample format `s16_le`, will be read as `int16` values in the range `-2**15 <= x < 2**15`. Floating point `float32` or `float64` are assumed to be in the range `-1 < x < 1`. That is where I assume the distortion comes from.

You could also try to just normalize using something like `sd.play(x / np.max(abs(x)), samplerate)`